# Letter inside square

Tags: css

I would like to create a text like that:
[image]

My question is, how can I create it using CSS?
The closest solution I've found was unicode with circles:
①②③

Comment: Why the downvote? Is the answer obvious?

Comment: I am shure you can find a free font with letters inside squares.

Comment: For the short and sweet answer go to this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yugg/0rpw7aLk/ 3 lines of HTML and 6 lines of CSS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by simply creating something like the HTML and CSS below:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#">1</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">2</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">3</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">4</a> </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px #888;
    line-height: 25px;
}
li a {
    display: block;
}
```

[See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/r84h8o9m/)

To add the numbers with CSS before/after selectors-[See this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/exvj6Lpa/)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion using a span is better than using a custom font because of two reasons

1. Support across all browsers - Many browsers don't [support custom font](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-face)
2. It is one extra resource download (font file) for the browser so it will affect performance and contribute to the overall page load time.

Comment: In your opinion, would span be the best fit?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can always style each letter differently by assigning classes individually and applying some specificity but that could be more work than it's worth and very hard to maintain. I would recommend lettering.js and you can find it in Github for free download.

here are some links to get you started.

[Ahandling Web Typograhy](http://trentwalton.com/2011/01/18/controlling-web-typography/)

[Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/)

[lettering.js download on GitHub](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js)